# NoClassDefFoundError in import when using maven

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror, stanford-nlp

I'm using maven to build a project.
I got some library imports in my class. Especially `edu.stanford.nlp.time.*;`

I use `mvn compile` and everthing is okay.
When I try to execute the program via `mvn exec:java` ... it starts but fails at some point because of

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class edu.stanford.nlp.time.XMLUtils
```

This only happened today. A few days ago everything was fine.
I cannot recreate what I did wrong.

Does anyone of you have an idea?

sincerly

Comment: It is probably a problem with the scope of the dependency.

Comment: If it compiles ok, but fails at runtime it is an optional transient dependency that is missing.  Figure out which jar the missing class is in an just add the dependency in your pom.

Comment: Can we see the relevant part of you pom please?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you use Spring framework or something else

not enought info to say exactly.
But seems issue happens during creation of context or some kind of initialization

I mean some missing classes can be mentioned in xml configuration e.g.

Answer (score 0):

The NoClassDefFoundError http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html appears when the class is available in your source code but the class can not be initialized.

If you have a static code block check if any errors happen. Here the most dangerous patterns in your case are probably anything to do with classloading Class.forName

But if it only happens with maven it is more probable that one of your imports in this XMLUtils is not available in the runtime scope. Youp probably reference something in the test scope. 
To analyse the different scopes I normally use the antrun plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html